# GStreamer's autovideosink missing for command line tools - Debian 9.4

Tags: c, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, gst-launch

The problem is only present when using GStreamer command line tools.  C programs that contain "autovideosink" compile and run as expected.

`gst-inspect-1.0 autovideosink`

returns

`No such element or plugin 'autovideosink'`

and

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink`

returns

`WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "autovideosink"`

I am running Debian 9.4.  I installed gstreamer with the following command:

`sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools`

Comment: Debug it with `strace`.

Answer (score 0):

The element [autovideosink](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-autovideosink.html) is provided by the gstreamer plugin `autodetect`, which in turn is contained in the Debian package [gstreamer1.0-plugins-good](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gstreamer1.0-plugins-good&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all).  Try to find the plugin on your system:

> $ locate libgstautodetect.so
>   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstautodetect.so

Since it is on your system somehow, maybe your C program is 32 bit and `gst-launch-1.0` is 64 bit (or vice versa).

Debugging gstreamer using [GST_DEBUG](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gst-running.html) is more adequate than `strace`:

> GST_DEBUG=INFO gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink